# Is it possible to use AWS service account in dotnet application instead AWS credentials

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, k8s-serviceaccount

Currently, my dotnet application is using AWS credentials but I would like to replace it with service account token. I don't see a way to do that in AWS documentation.

Comment: What is a "service account token"?

Comment: Would like to use Service account (K8s) for my application. Service account will have a token generated in the cluster. So, I was thinking that If I can replace AWS credentials from the application to somehow use the token? Not sure if that's a thing. I don't know how other people implement this kind of scenario

Comment: If you want to call AWS APIs, you will need AWS credentials. Temporary credentials can be 'generated' using the AWS Security Token Service. So, you could write your own code that might accept one form of authentication and then generate AWS credentials. Not sure if that meets your use-case.